# Login in linked in from ios app

Tags: ios, swift

I am building an app which requires linked in login. I am opening the browser from my app and want to login from there.Now I need OAuth2_access_token when I try to log in.How to do that?Help is always appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I use a super simple guide and library called "Singly", which I use for OAuth 2.0 authentication. While it is not getting updated anymore, it still works perfectly and it is a great place to start. Once you get up and running with OAuth 2.0, you will realize that it is very simple and easy to use for the most part. At that point I would then recommend you look at other libraries as the one I'm suggesting will not be updated anymore (as far as I understand).

You can find the Singly OAuth 2.0 library and tutorial here: https://github.com/Singly/ios_example/wiki/Getting-Started

This is also another great and simple library you can use for OAuth 2.0: https://github.com/honghaoz/Google-OAuth2.0-Demo-iOS

**Update**

Sorry I didn't realize you wanted it in Swift. Here is a nice and very easy to use OAuth 2.0 Swift library you can use. It comes with documentation on how to use it too: https://github.com/p2/OAuth2

Comment: well,thanks for the help,but you should have checked that I am asking for swift,not objective-c.

Comment: @NiloyMahmud Oh sorry sir. My fault. I have updated my answer with an awesome Swift library for OAuth 2.0 which is very easy to use as well.